# What is meaning of this line?

Tags: c++, opencv

- I am reading one paper and in that one line is there like

  ```
  skin_map(row, col) = 1.0
  ```
- Where **skin_map** is cv::Mat of opencv.Unable to understand meaning of above line.AnyBody help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::Mat` has an `operator(`) that receives row and col. This returns a reference to that position in the mat. The remainder of the line sets that position to `1.0`.

> **Mat::operator()**
>
> Extracts a rectangular submatrix.
>
> C++: `Mat Mat::operator()(Range rowRange, Range colRange) const`

Comment: Let's say that instead of a `cv::Mat`, you had a 

`vector< vector<double> > skin_mat;`
and you would call:
`skin_mat[row][col]=1.0`

It's the same idea.

Comment: but when i use this in my code it gives error like no match for call to ‘(cv::Mat) (int, int)

Comment: row and col should be `Range` objects. not ints

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat):

> OpenCV C++ **n-dimensional** dense array class

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The `Mat` class have an overloaded [function-call operator](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6) that returns a reference to a cell in the "n-dimensional array", where the arguments are the positions in each separate dimension.

The variable `skin_map` is apparently a two-dimensional `Mat` instance, a.k.a. a matrix, with rows and columns.

So what the assignment does is set one specific cell in the matrix to `1.0`.